# Angular 2 splice removes first in array

Tags: angular, typescript

When using splice in Angular 2 - the front end array removes whatever value is in the first row. The backend removes the correct one.

```
deleteCustomer(customer: Customer){
    //opt1 - removes first
    this.customers.splice(this.customers.indexOf(customer),1);
    //opt2 - this works although it will loop all records
    this.customers.forEach((t, i) => { 
        if (t.customer_id === customer.customer_id) { 
          this.customers.splice(i, 1); }
     });
    //the backend deletes the correct record in both options
    return this.http.delete(`${this.customersUrl}/${customer['customer_id']}`)
    .subscribe(
        data => console.log(data),
        error => console.error(error)
    );
}
```

Preferably i would like to use option1 - what am i missing here?

Below a part of my form:

```html
      <div class="widget-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" [formGroup]="customerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
          <fieldset>
            <legend><strong>Customer</strong> form</legend>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="customer_id-field" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">
                Id
              </label>
              <div class="col-md-7">
                <input type="text" formControlName="customer_id"  id="customer_id-field" class="form-control" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Where's the code that calls `deleteCustomer` ?

Comment: Try to step through the function using your browsers dev tools. `this.customers.indexOf(customer)` probably isn't returning what you think it is

Comment: Yes, i guess it is a different customer object with same id. Instead of `forEach` you can use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and then `slice()`.